# Простейшее отображение информации и графики на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, svg

Делаю отображение статистики для своего сервера: http://repo.centerix.ru/stormserver-modstate . Подскажите, как максимально просто отобразить информацию.

К примеру я хочу вывести статистику по запросам за последнюю минуту, посекундно. Я исхожу из того, что это сервер и лишней нагрузки там быть не должно и вся нагрузка должна быть на клиенте. Значит, максимум, что я могу: вывести на странице массив чисел.

Вопрос, чем можно преобразовать массив чисел в график или другое визуальное представление, более понятное человеку? Навскидку, могу предположить, что так можно сделать через JavaScript, svg, и кажется html5.

Поделитесь примерами. Например, реализации того же графика. Варианты без примеров не нужны, интересует только практическая реализация, которую можно взять и использовать.

Answer (score 1):

[d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) и [пример линейной диаграммы](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)

Answer (score 0):

Я у себя использую [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). HTML5, SVG, мультитач на мобилках, динамическое обновление, ещё вроде бы совместимость с древними IE, вот это вот всё. Примеров [полно на офсайте](http://www.highcharts.com/demo).

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, они не бесплатные? А по функциональности, за исключением поддержки древних IE на том же уровне, что d3?

Comment: Судя по примерам, до функциональности d3 не дотягивает) Но всё бесплатное и довольно легко используемое, полнофункциональные графики построить быстро и без нервов — имхо, самое то.

Comment: Для некоммерческого использования они бесплатны. А вот для коммерческого - нет. http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html